Why is the accuracy of my Sequential Model in Keras is more than 1 during Epochs?
I am currently doing a classification problem on recognition the facial emotions.
I am using a Kaggle Notebook to do so as it supports 2 GPUs in free quota.
And here is the model
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    data_augmentation = Sequential([
        RandomFlip('horizontal', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)),
        RandomZoom(0.1),
        RandomRotation(0.1)
    ], name='Data_Augmentation-1')

    model = Sequential([
        #data_augmentation,

        #Rescaling(1. / 255, input_shape=(256, 256, 3)),
        Input(shape=(256, 256, 3)),

        Conv2D(4, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='Conv2D-1'),
        MaxPooling2D(name='MaxPool2D-1'),

        Conv2D(8, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='Conv2D-2'),
        MaxPooling2D(name='MaxPool2D-2'),

        Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='Conv2D-3'),
        MaxPooling2D(name='MaxPool2D-3'),

        Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='Conv2D-4'),
        MaxPooling2D((3, 3), name='MaxPool2D-4'),

        Flatten(name='Flatten-1'),

        Dense(64, activation='relu', name='Dense-1'),
        Dense(128, activation='relu', name='Dense-2'),
        Dense(256, activation='relu', name='Dense-3'),
        Dense(len(class_names), name='Dense-OUTPUT'),

    ], name='Sequential')

    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
history = model.fit(data, epochs=10)
history = history.history

The total number of classes here is 6.
So this is the verbose of epoch.

Accuracy score must be between 0 and 1. But this is giving us accuracy of above 1. Why is it giving like this so?

I believe you should use sparse_categorical_accuracy as a metric to track accuracy if you're using SparseCategoricalCrossentropy loss

Also I've found other people having trouble with metrics when using >1 GPU, from the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/distributed_training it seems that the model definition and call to compile should be contained in the with strategy.scope(): block

Yeah, even after changing the intendentation that is putting the definition and compile functions inside with strategy.scope(): block it is still showing the same epoch results.

In the metrics part of model.compile it's explained that the string 'accuracy' is interpreted dynamically depending on the loss. Meaning with SparseCategoricalCrossentropy loss, you should also get SparseCategoricalCrossentropy accuracy. But maybe this doesn't work with a multi-GPU strategy. I don't know when exactly the string gets converted to the real function, and if that happens inside the scope or not. Did you try to use tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy directly as a metric?

On the other side, in this tutorial part they also use MirroredStrategy and 'accuracy' string.. and it looks pretty similar to your code.

This is the current bugs found in Keras 3 https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/19280. It should be fixed by now, otherwise open on ticket on github. Note, Keras 3 in its early age, so better to open ticket on github rather than here the moment.
